div with position: absolute gets the wrong width from the child image, in Firefox only


.div1 {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  background: lightcoral;
}

.img-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.img1 {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 50%;
}
<div class="div1">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x300" alt="" class="img1">
  </div>
</div>



Chrome result (expected result):

Firefox result (wrong result):

As you can see, in Firefox the width of the green div is just some random value, and not the width of its descendants (I fail to see any logic behind it).
Images must be able to have variable width, so this solution won't work for me (can't set fixed width on .img-container).
What am I doing wrong?

Can confirm this FF bug on macOS

" in Firefox the width of the green div is just some random value" - it's actually the natural width of the image (600) rather than random. It seems to be taking that rather than the computed width of the image.

As Chrime and Safari both seem to give the logical result, it may be worth you reporting the problem with FF to Mozilla.

This does appear to highlight an inconsistency between Edge/Chrome/Safari and Firefox.
If the grandparent has no explicit height set, the only height in this case being given by the padding-bottom, then FF seems to take the natural width of the image, not its width calculated in relation to height: 100%.
Giving div1 height of 25cqw (to be the same as the padding, padding being calculated in terms of widths not heights) plus box-sizing set at border-box to 'absorb' the padding, rectifies this, but of course may upset something else if there is other material within div1.


.div1 {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  background: lightcoral;
  height: 25cqw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.img1 {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 50%;
}
<div class="div1">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x300" alt="" class="img1">
  </div>
</div>



So, this gives a workaround for the problem as set, but you need to look out for other dependencies in the real-life case.

In Firefox, the width of the img container isn't random. In fact it is the original width of the img (600px), CSS alone can't determine the rendered width when the image's height is based on a percentage.. What exactly do you want to achieve?
if you really want to force it, use JS to determine the image width on page load.
function changeWidth() {
  const container = document.querySelector('img-container');
  const img = document.querySelector('img1');
  container.style.width = img.clientWidth + 'px';
}
window.onload = changeWidth
windw.onresize = changeWidth


I don't entirely understand this as Chrome can determine the width.

CSS does not have a built-in mechanism for calculating layout properties "in reverse." While setting the height as a percentage will adjust the height based on the parent, CSS cannot use that percentage-based height to dynamically calculate the width unless both dimensions are explicitly provided or they are tied to intrinsic values like an image's aspect ratio.

try explicitly defining the img height, then the container will resize perfectly.

So how does Chrome do it OK in CSS without explicit height setting?

it is probably specific to Chrome (probably it has a method of tackling this). But that's what I know generally

Safari gives the same result as Chrome and FF is very little used in comparison so is there a reference for what should happen generally (before someone reports a bug to one or other of the platforms)?

My guess is that there's something to do with how Chrome and FF handle cyclic dependency differently. I saw many simillar problems when the width depends on the aspect ratio of the child and FF behaves often differently from all other major browsers. FF just doesn't recalculated the parent width after calculating the width of the replaced element.

@SyndRain agreed, most likely FF doing things in a strange/different order. Certainly its behaviour does not appear to be the general one.

Right, likely highly related to this Temani's post. The width of  img-container doesn't refer to the width of the img after its width is recalculated because of height:100% and its intrinsic aspect ratio. Based on its conclusion we can't say FF's behavior is wrong, though it is indeed different from all other browsers.

Yes, seems likely it’s related, or at least the respective developers’ interpretations are @SyndRain

Firefox is a little different when it comes to absolute positioning. Try to understand what actually absolute position works. The element having abs with height: 100% will cover fully if the parent container is also 100%
you also have a padding-bottom i don't understand why do you need padding bottom, this will make your children appear smaller.
Try adding  width: 100%; to img-container. i tinkered with your code in the inspector. it seemed to fix it. Try and let me know how it goes

I think you may have missed the point of this question. The padding-bottom is (the only) thing that is giving the grandparent any height.
